# Alignment problem when changing label font size with radio buttons in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I am working with the bootstrap radio button style and I have a problem with the alignment between radio buttons and their labels.

The main problem arises when I change the font size of the label: The radio button stays with the same size (obviously, because I didn't change it) at the original place, and the label change its size moving itself a little below (depending on the font size; the higher size, the longer movement).

Here you can see the alignment problem:

[image]

I also leave you here my code:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form name="ejercicio_p1_form" method="POST" action="/response_p1_exercise">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="radio" id="radio_p1_1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_1" value="1" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label style="font-size:30px" class="radio custom-control-label" for="p1_ejer_1"> Option 1</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="radio" align="center" id="radio_p1_2">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_2" value="2" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label style="font-size:30px" class="radio custom-control-label" for="p1_ejer_2"> Option 2</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bootstrap` `label` has `:before` and `:after` with `position: absolute` and `top: .25rem`. This makes the radio circle to be fixed. We can calculate its position with `top: calc(foo)`.

We know, that `height` of radio circle is `1rem`, `height` of `label` is changing, so it is 100%. To find top left corner coordinate of radio circle we take 50% of `label` `height`, half of circle should be above center, half lower, so subtract 0.5rem.

And our formula is: `top: calc((100% - 1rem)/2)`

Look in snippet how it looks.

```css
.label-style {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.label-style:before, .label-style:after {
  top: calc((100% - 1rem)/2) !important;
}

.font-size30 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.font-size50 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.font-size62 {
  font-size: 62px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form name="ejercicio_p1_form" method="POST" action="/response_p1_exercise">
  <div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="radio" id="radio_p1_1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_1" value="1" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label class="radio custom-control-label label-style font-size30" for="p1_ejer_1"> Option 1</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="radio" align="center" id="radio_p1_2">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_2" value="2" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label class="radio custom-control-label label-style font-size30" for="p1_ejer_2"> Option 2</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="radio" id="radio_p1_1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_3" value="1" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label class="radio custom-control-label label-style font-size50" for="p1_ejer_3"> Option 1</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="radio" align="center" id="radio_p1_2">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_4" value="2" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label class="radio custom-control-label label-style font-size50" for="p1_ejer_4"> Option 2</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="radio" id="radio_p1_1">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_5" value="1" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label class="radio custom-control-label label-style font-size62" for="p1_ejer_5"> Option 1</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="radio" align="center" id="radio_p1_2">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="p1_ejer" id="p1_ejer_6" value="2" onclick="submit_form_p1_exercise()">
            <label class="radio custom-control-label label-style font-size62" for="p1_ejer_6"> Option 2</label>
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```